# How do you unshare or remove a person from your iCloud photo album?

Tags: icloud

How do you unshare or remove a person from your iCloud photo album?

Answer (score 4):

On the Photos app on OS X:

1. Open the Photos App
2. Go to the "Shared" tab
3. Select the album you'd like to modify
   [image: Photos app, shared album]
4. Click on the circle with a face inside icon on the top left of the app, a menu will appear
   [image: Shared album preferences]
5. Select the person you'd like to remove from the album, and click on the arrow right next to their name
   [image: Shared album, unshare pop up]
6. A new menu will pop up; select "Remove subscriber".

On the Photos app for iOS:

1. Go to the "Shared" screen, select the album you want to modify

[image: shared album iOS]

2. Look at the bottom of the screen for the "People" button, and tap on it.
3. A preferences menu will appear, with the name of the people you've shared the album with on top. Select the person you'd like to stop sharing with.

[image: shared album preferences]

4. It will show you the contact for that person (if you have it on your phone). Scroll to the bottom and tap on the "Remove Subscriber" text in red.

[image: remove subscriber iOS photo app, shared album]