# Once a link to a photo has been created in iCloud, is there a way to invalidate the link & remove the photo?

Tags: icloud, photos.app

Once a link to a photo has been created in iCloud, is there a way to invalidate the link & remove the photo?
Deleting the photo does not invalidate the link AFIK.  The photo is gone from my devices, but the created link still shows the photo.

Answer (score 2):

If you shared the picture in an album (Photo Stream), you can learn how to do it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199832/how-do-you-unshare-or-remove-a-person-from-your-icloud-photo-album).

If you shared the picture alone (by clicking "Copy iCloud link"), you have to :

- Go to the link on a computer, while logged in to the iCloud account from which the image was shared.

For example https://www.icloud.com/photos/#XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX

- Click on the three dots (upper right) > Stop sharing

[image: How to stop sharing iCloud picture]

Note that every picture will expire 30 days after being shared. Also, if someone made an offline copy of the photo and/or saved it to their library, removing the share link does not claw that copy back - it only prevents new viewing.